# Indepedent Controls/Fields on Multirecord form DB ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016, multiple-records

I have created a simple inventory management Access DB which in its basic functionality works perfectly.I would like to start to make some polish here and there and I've found the next issue.

I do have a main form for inventory transactions. It has a Header section (with a table of transactions header as a recordsource) and a details section (datasheet type subform into the main form; which means a multiple records form where I can add or remove multiple lines for each header transaction and it is linked to the main form, that works OK).

In this detail/lines subform I have the fields: Category (combobox), Item (combobox) and Quantity (category and item fields are linked to "master categories" table and "master items" table).

I do want to add the following behavior:

- When I select a category on category combobox field, the item field updates its selection to show only the items in the selected category.

I can do this easily on a single record form with this code:

```
Private Sub Category_AfterUpdate()

Me.Item.Requery

End Sub
```

On the Item field datasource I do have a simple query:

```
SELECT ID,DESC FROM ARTICLES WHERE ARTICLES.CATEGORY = [FORMS]![SUBFORM].[CATEGORY]
```

This works flawlessly with a single record form.

However as this is a multiple lines/records form when I select a category on a line, it updates the "Item" selection field for ALL the lines/records, even changing values depending on the selected category.

Is there a way to update controls/fields in an independent way for each record on a datasheet form? Let's say something like:

```
Private Sub Category_AfterUpdate()

Me.Item(current record).Requery

End Sub
```

I'm thinking on adding an index to the combobox article field and update only the field on that index but I don't know how to proceed or if it's possible to do that.

Any ideas or workaround to do this?

Comment: No, cannot update/requery a single record. Not sure what you mean by 'changing values'. Value saved should not change just because combobox is requeried. It is true that DESC value will not be available for display when combobox filter excludes those items. This is a well known and documented issue of cascading combobox. BTW, DESC is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: Sorry, the field it's not named DESC, it's named "Descripcion" (spanish word), not reserved.

And yes it's not "changing" values, it's showing them or not due the filtering on the category combobox, looking like the values entered disappear.

So there is no way or workaround to update a combobox values for just a single record?

Comment: Also a reserved word but might not cause issue. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html

Comment: If you need to help the user insert the right values.  instead look up cascading comboboxes and put as many of them as you need in the header with a button.  Make sure the cascading comboboxes are unbound.  Then in the button click event insert a record based on the values in comboboxes.